# How is clear page cache in the CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I use CodeIgniter. Always part of my page is cache and don't remove by `Ctrl+F5` in the browser. When I change the name page in the view it worked !!!?

How can clear page cache in the CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 10):

You need to manually delete the cached items in the `application/cache` folder.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html is the current 3.x link....

Answer (score 4):

```
function delete_cache($uri_string=null)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $path = $CI->config->item('cache_path');
    $path = rtrim($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    $cache_path = ($path == '') ? APPPATH.'cache/' : $path;

    $uri =  $CI->config->item('base_url').
            $CI->config->item('index_page').
            $uri_string;

    $cache_path .= md5($uri);

    return unlink($cache_path);
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 4):

```
public function clear_path_cache($uri)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $path = $CI->config->item('cache_path');
    //path of cache directory
    $cache_path = ($path == '') ? APPPATH.'cache/' : $path;

    $uri =  $CI->config->item('base_url').
    $CI->config->item('index_page').
    $uri;
    $cache_path .= md5($uri);

    return @unlink($cache_path);
}




/**
 * Clears all cache from the cache directory
 */
public function clear_all_cache()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $path = $CI->config->item('cache_path');

    $cache_path = ($path == '') ? APPPATH.'cache/' : $path;

    $handle = opendir($cache_path);
    while (($file = readdir($handle))!== FALSE) 
    {
        //Leave the directory protection alone
        if ($file != '.htaccess' && $file != 'index.html')
        {
           @unlink($cache_path.'/'.$file);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);       
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

### Codeigniter 3

I added an endpoint to a controller

```php
function delete_cache() {
    preg_match("/(\/index.php)(?<endpoint>\/[\w.-\/]*)/", 
    $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], $result);
    $this->output->delete_cache($result["endpoint"]);
    redirect($result["endpoint"]);
}
```

Then I added a refresh button pointed to this endpoint.
When the user click on the refresh button the current cached file will be delete, then redirect to the page.

Comment: Is that regex pattern really intending to include a range of characters from a literal dot to a forward slash?

Answer (score -6):

It is probably in a `session`.Try deleting your cookies.

Comment: i deleting the cookies in the chrome browser but not ok.

Comment: its saved server side, as described there: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html