# Query caching in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, caching

I want to cache a query in CodeIgniter. What I did for my test is make a controller, that I named `show.php`:

```
class Show extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('rejaal_show');
}

public function _remap($method = '',$param = array())
{
    $method = intval($method);
    $this->output->cache(5);
    var_dump ($this->rejaal_show->temp($method));
}
}
```

And a model that I named `rejaal_show.php`:

```
public function temp($id)
{
    $this->db->cache_on();
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get('system_store_table');
    return $query->result();
}
```

When I call `http://localhost/rejaal/show/1` for the first time, it will show a result, but when I call it for the second time, it does not show anything.

I should delete the query cache file to show it again? How should I solve this problem?

With special thanks for your attention.

Comment: Topical page for anyone who wants to plagiarize content as part of a late answer: [How is clear page cache in the CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7422013/2943403) and here is the direct CodeIgniter documentation which describes how to enable caching: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm that you have set `$db['default']['cachedir']` to the path of a writable folder in `application/config/database.php` and that when the query is first run it creates a cache file in there?

The only other reason I can think of for it failing is by your use of the `_remap` override.  I have not used db caching using `_remap`, but know that CodeIgniter creates a folder called controller+action in your cache folder, and might not be handled very well if using remap?  Someone correct me if I am wrong about this.

Answer (score 0):

In the CodeIgniter User Guide page for [Web Page Caching](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html), it says:

***Because of the way CodeIgniter stores content for output, caching will only work if you are generating display for your controller with a [view](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html).***

Do your `var_dump` inside a view.

Comment: To enable caching, put the following tag in any of your controller functions:

$this->output->cache(n);