# CodeIgniter won't display the changes on a view

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, web, frontend

I'm working on a project using CI. But i'm having a problem. I have a view that isn't displaying its changes. I really don't know what its happening.

Lets say that I have `application/views/store.php` and the Store controller that loads that view. I update the php file but it doesn't change. 
Anyone has any idea of what it could be?

Comment: try clearing the page cache http://stackoverflow.com/a/7422573/3008050

Comment: Yeah, i tried clearing the cache, disabled the cache, restarted the server, deleted the whole code. Nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
           $data['title'] = "page title";

           $this->load->view('page',$data);
    }
}
```